# Shortage of Compute Engine Resource US

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This morning my e2 vm instance in us-east1 went down randomly, I logged onto GCP to start it up again and keep getting the following error:

> Failed to start <vm_name>: A e2-micro VM instance is currently
> unavailable in the us-east1-b zone. Alternatively, you can try your
> request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later
> time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.

I've tried with another e2-small instance and am also unable to get allocation - Google has nothing regarding this issue on the outage page, but there is a post on cloud forums where a lot of people seem to be experiencing the same:

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Shortage-of-Compute-Engine-Resource-in-us-central-1/m-p/492518

Has anyone experienced this before and if so how long was the resolution? I'm hesitant to migrate my production services to a different region if this is going to be resolved.

What I find really strange is there being no mention of this on their outage page, this seems like a pretty big deal - am I perhaps looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Very small instance sizes are in high demand. Resize the instance larger. Search Stack Overflow. This question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1):

As from your question I could figure out that resources might not be available for the us-east1-b zone possibly due to traffic.

As said by @John Hanley, This is a common issue for me with the small instance type because of high demand.

GCP's goal is to make sure that there are available resources in all zones. This type of issue is rare, when a situation like this occurs or is about to occur, GCP team is notified immediately and the issue is investigated.

**Seems you already tried possible solutions:**

1)Launch a larger instance (Changing the Machine Configuration)

2)Select a different region (hesitant to migrate your production services to a different region )

If possible you can try to decrease the need of your instance (eg. decrease RAM, CPUs, GPUs). It might work if you are lucky.

GCP recommends deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. Please review official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/scalable-and-resilient-apps) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.

These issues happen mostly during the weekends & holidays (like from Friday to Sunday) daytime EST, has a high probability of unavailable resources.

If you want to know how long you are expected to wait : within 1.5 to 3 business days becomes normal in my case.

**Edit :**

Please follow the guidelines mentioned in the official document for [Troubleshooting errors that you might encounter while creating or updating VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability)